# Linux portable USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

Если я установлю на USB диск к примеру Ubuntu, можно ли будет загрузиться с такой флешки на любом компьютере (как с помощью Live USB) или во время установки происходят "железоспецифичные" операции и то что работает на моем железе не запустится на другом. Live USB не могу использовать так как хочу чтобы сохранялись все изменения в системе после перезагрузки.
Как вы решали такие проблемы?

Comment: Эээ.. Вопрос же понятен, зачем закрывать с требованием переформулировать??

Answer (score 2):

Установочный образ Ubuntu как раз предназначен для Live-работы. Вы загружаете компьютер с установочного образа и далее можете либо работать с него, либо начать установку. Поэтому если вы создадите загрузочную флешку из официального ISO-образа, то сможете работать на любом компьютере, поддерживающем загрузку с флешки.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но проблема в том, что на Live образе нельзя устанавливать софт, драйверы, хранить документы... После перезагрузки все пропадает. Есть конечно вариант создать раздел для своих данных, но это не решает вопрос с установкой видеодрайвера.